# NoMethodError: undefined method `liquidity_manager?' for #<Order:0x007fd9b7a4cf98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My solution throws NoMethodError. This is what I have done below:

**Order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

**Member.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def liquidity_manager?
    @is_liquidity_manager ||= self.class.liquidity_managers.include?(self.email)
  end

  def liquidity_managers
    ENV['LM_ACCOUNTS'].split(',')
  end
end
```

**rake task logic**

The logic in *lib/update_order_tags.rake*

```
num_counts = (Order.count/10).ceil
num_counts.times do |i|
  Order.all.offset(i*10).limit(10).find_each do |g|
    if g.tags.blank? # am saving on only the blank fields
      if g.liquidity_manager? # The error is here
        g.tags = 'LM'
        g.save!
      else
        g.tags = 'Customer'
        g.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How do I reference the `liquidity_manager?` method to be useful for me in lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the advise given to me by @sawa in the answer section, here is what I have done to make it work.

```
num_counts = (Order.count/10).ceil
num_counts.times do |i|
  Order.all.offset(i*10).limit(10).find_each do |g|
    if g.tags.blank? 
      if g.member.liquidity_manager? # So this easily gets to Member.rb to reference liquidity_manager? method.
        g.tags = 'LM'
        g.save!
      else
        g.tags = 'Customer'
        g.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `Order#liquidity_manager?` in `Member.rb`, which is not automatically loaded by Rails. You have to either explicitly load the file `Member.rb`, or rename that file to `/app/models/order.rb`.

Comment: Its a logic in a rake task which is the `lib/` path. Rake file cannot be dropped into `/app/models/order.rb`. Seem I will have to take the other suggestion by making sure the method is available in `lib/`

Comment: No, I am not mentioning the lib file. It's about the your `Member.rb` file.

Comment: So, you think a `before_action :liquidity_manager?` on member.rb will work?

Comment: You mean `Member.rb` instead of `member.rb`? If so, yes as long as you can get to that file.

Comment: Yes. Member.rb. Forgive my typo